# I want to install 3 dll's for my work project, but i don't know if the dll's will work in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-framework-version, windows-forms-core

The dll's are:

-CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework

-CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore

-Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Data.UnitTesting

I'm trying to update an old project to the new c# updates.

Comment: The issue is not VS.  It is the target version of Net/Core that is issue.  The dlls may work if the target version in project matches the version of Net that the dlls were built with and the type of project (x86, 32 bit, 64 bit).  They also may work with newer version of Net/Core.  Did the machine and/or OS change since last built?  This could also make difference if code will run.

Comment: Yes, the machine is different. They gave me this activity but I don't know where to start to update the code.

Comment: Solve one error at a time.  Check web if newer versions of library are available.  Choose a version of Net/Core that you want to use for your target.  Start by doing clean build on each project and see what errors you get.  You may decide to use Latest version of Core or an older version.  You also may want to do the updates in stages and pick an intermediate version for your target.  Get a schedule of when intermediate releases are needed and final release.

Answer (score 0):

It is the .Net version that must be compatible with any loaded dlls, and newer visual studio versions do support older .Net versions. If you are updating from .Net framework to .Net core/5/6 you might just have to test it.

.Net core/5/6 is not backwards compatible with .Net framework, since some functionality have been removed. I think you can still *try* to load a dll written for .Net framework, but if any removed functionality is called you will get a runtime failure. So you need to be diligent with testing.

I would expect libraries that does things like UI and communication to work less well, and libraries that mostly do things like computation, or wraps native functionality, to work better.

Comment: My .Net version is 7.1. Could you tell me any of these libraries? so that i can take a step forward.

Comment: @Fliperama Net 7 is in preview at the moment, perhaps you are looking at the visual studio version? I.e. vs 2022 17.1? Regardless, it is unlikely anyone can tell you if these libraries will work. Either just try and see if it works, or ask the vendors if they have updated versions.